# I get 'Specified cast is not valid' when passing arguments to class instance initialization (new), and direct cast is not casting to nullable integer

Tags: vb.net, casting

I have a class called **ItemStringInteger** declared in a separate module (below):

```
 Public Class ItemStringInteger
        Private _itemtext As String
        Private _itemvalue As Integer?
        Public Property Text() As String
            Get
                Return _itemtext
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _itemtext = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property Value() As Integer?
            Get
                Return _itemvalue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer?)
                _itemvalue = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Sub New(ByVal displayText As String, ByVal value As Integer?)
            _itemtext = displayText
            _itemvalue = value
        End Sub
        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return _itemtext
        End Function
    End Class
```

In form load i have this code (the line with error has comment):

```
Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter("Select int_value , char_value  from [References] where [group]='SIO_sio_type' ", Connection), DT As New DataTable
DA.Fill(DT)

With comboSIOType
    .DataSource = DT
    .DisplayMember = "char_value"
    .ValueMember = "int_value"
End With

With comboSIOFilter
    For Each dr As DataRow In DT.Rows
        Dim Y As New ItemStringInteger(dr("char_value"), dr("int_value")) 'Error is in this line
        .Items.Add(Y)
    Next
End With
```

The Error message is `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'`
The values in runtime are:

`dr("char_value") = "склад общий"` 
 `dr("int_value")=1`

If i replace the line with error, with any of the following no error is raised:

1) `Dim Y As New ItemStringInteger(dr("char_value"), Nothing)`

1) `Dim Y As New ItemStringInteger("some text", 2)`

If replace `integer?` to `integer` in **ItemStringInteger** class all works fine (with initial code in form load), but i would prefer `integer?` to be there

Hope the problem is clear. No other code parts affect this issue. Seems the answer is somehow related to nullable integer type and casting from datarow value type.. Thank you...

Comment: I just spent a few minutes reformatting your code so that it's clearly readable. Please post correctly formatted code in future.

Comment: Your constructor (which is what a `New` method is called) is declared with two parameters. Those parameters are type `String` and `Integer?`.  In both cases, you're not passing a `String` reference to the first parameter, so that's one issue.  Without seeing the whole error message, either in the text you posted or your screenshot, we are forced to guess at the exact issue.  I reckon that it's probably that one of your fields is null, which means that you're passing `DBNull.Value` where a `String` is expected.

Comment: You should start by turning `Option Strict On` for the project and fixing the issues it flags.  If a `String` is expected then you need to make sure that a `String` is passed.

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney for prompt respond. 'dr("char_value")' - is a strnig and holding the string at that moment (it show th string in debug during mouse over) the 'dr("int_value")' is =1 (the actual type is byte) <br> 'Dim Y As New ItemStringInteger(dr("char_value"), Nothing)' - this also works fine, the problem is definitely around 'dr("int_value")' while passing as argument where integer? (nullable) is expected

Comment: Again, turn `Option Strict On` first. That is highly likely to make things clearer.

Comment: If i change the class to have `integer` instead of `integer?`,  then all works fine, but i most probably need nullable int. And why ctype is unable to convert `dr("int_value")` which is =1 to nullableof(integer) ? (loop the picture)  ........ thanks

Comment: Seems setting `Option Strict On` doesn't helps at all (though i didn't restart visual studio).

Comment: I didn't expect setting `Option Strict On` to solve the problem, but it likely makes solving the problem (and avoiding others) easier. Now that `Option Strict` is `On`. Show us the exact code you're using now, show us the full error message, show us exactly where it occurs and tell us exactly what data is in use at the time. You should [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes i knew what you had asked to turn `option strict on` for. The thing is that, i am very new in this (and any) website, and it takes some efforts to format the way you require ... i will now briefly drop the code and the porblem again here

Answer (score 0):

The beneath are working variants and the answer(s):

```
Dim Y As New ItemStringInteger(dr("char_value"), CInt(dr("int_value")))
```

---

```
Dim Y As New ItemStringInteger(dr("char_value"), Conversion.CTypeDynamic(Of Nullable(Of Integer))(dr("int_value")))
```

---

```
Dim Y As New ItemStringInteger(dr("char_value"), Conversion.CTypeDynamic(Of Integer?)(dr("int_value")))
```

---

```
Dim Y As New ItemStringInteger(dr("char_value"), CType(dr("int_value"), Integer))
```

`Ctype` - doesn't covert to nullable(of T), but it is ok to pass `integer` where `integer?` is expected. Besides datarow("columnX") never has stored `nothing` value, unless the datarow isn't nothing itself (which is not what we expect is possible to be at that point). So either casting with `Conversion.CTypeDynamic` to `integer?` or with other conversation functions casting to `integer` . Thank you @jmcilhinney for you efforts to help!